# SSE ( Server Sent Events ) with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, server-sent-events

I would like to use server sent events for live comments on live videos on Facebook, as described in the [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments).

The documentation asks me to send a `GET` request to `https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/{live-video-id}/live_comments`.

How does SSE work post this, and how would I implement this in RoR? Would each connection also occupy one thread with RoR?